# Xcode 10.1 getting Freezes

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, xcode10.1

I updated my OS to Mojave & separately installed **Xcode 9.2, 9.4 & 10.1**.

**Xcode 9.2 & 9.4** works good but **Xcode 10.1** getting freezes sometimes. Everything freezes except the mouse cursor. Mouse cursor was moving but it couldn't select anything. The only way to get rid of this is to reboot my Mac. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have vmware macos... I have also same problem... It occurs sometimes class page change... It frezee for one-two minitues then work good but when try to open another class it occurs again

Comment: Moreover, when define function in swift compiler try to replace "" with "" giving errorr seems 10.1 is buggy

Comment: I am facing similar kind of issues

Comment: Do you have SCNViews in your project?